# Django ordering using filtered foreignkey

Tags: python, sql, django

I have the following setup

```
class ModelA(Model):
    field = CharField()
    order = IntegerField()

    class Meta:
         ordering: ['order']

class UserOrder(Model):
    modela = ForeignKey(ModelA)
    user = ForeignKey(User)
    order = IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ['modela', 'user']
```

I'd like to order ModelA by the custom order stored in UserOrder. I can do this in SQL a follows:

```
SELECT * FROM modela a 
  LEFT JOIN userorder uo ON a.id = uo.modela_id
  WHERE uo.user_id = 1
  ORDER BY uo.order ASC, a.order ASC;
```

This will order by a custom order first, and the default order second.

I currently filter the queryset, and order it after the DB call, but I was hoping there was a way to order it right out of the DB in a single call using the Django ORM.

Comment: Shot in the dark: `ModelA.objects.filter(userorder__user__id=1).order_by('userorder__order', 'order')`?

Comment: Why do you think ordering after filtering would not be a single db call? It would.

Comment: what the two comments above said :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sum up:

```
ModelA.objects.filter(userorder__user__id=1).order_by('userorder__order', 'order')
```

and [Querysets in django are lazy](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/queries/#querysets-are-lazy), it means, as Daniel wrote, you can write your ORM how you want and  at the end, it will be a single db call once the queryset is evaluated.